# getTransaction() returning null

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, mining

On sending a number of concurrent transactions to geth running a private network with a small number of mining peers , i notice that transaction hashes are generated for each of those transaction , but most of the time , some of them do not get mined and the getTransaction method for the hashes of these transaction returns null. Why is this occurring ?

The ratio of these transactions is almost 10 : 1 (total transactions : null transactions). All other transactions get successfully mined.

I am mining only on the peers whereas the node that generates transaction is not mining . What is wrong here ?

Geth Instance details are - instance: Geth/v1.5.9-unstable-29645045/linux/go1.7.4

Comment: Are the transactions of equal size/gas cost?

Comment: Yes each transaction is generated in a similar way , with default gas and gasPrice and no other data.